# Grouping based on other variables

Tags: numpy, dask, python-xarray, geo

I have an Xarray dataset with **x** and **y** coordinates and 3 variables **agb**, **col** and **row**. You can have an overview looking at this (don't care about other coords/vars)

[image]

My goal is to group **agb** values based on **col** and **row** values, as shown here

[image]

and then produce a mean for each group, and assign the value to the corresponding **(col,row)** index in another DataArray, e.g. ( following the example above )

[image]

I can't figure out how to do it. I tried using the **.groupby()** method, but it works on coordinates and not on pairs taken from other variables.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance